# Add tooltip to @Html.Grid Column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tooltip, html-helper

I have the following @Html.Grid

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>  

columns.Add(c => c.NumEM).Titled(Html.DisplayNameFor(model =>
model.NumEM).ToString()).SortInitialDirection(GridSortDirection.Ascending);
columns.Add(c => c.NumVre).Titled(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NumVre).ToString());
columns.Add(c => c.LibYis).Titled(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LibYis).ToString());
columns.Add(c => c.LibYpr).Titled(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LibYpr).ToString());
columns.Add(c => c.LibPdtTitre).Titled(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LibPdtTitre).ToString());
columns.Add(c => c.LibSaiTitre).Titled(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LibSaiTitre).ToString());
columns.Add(c => c.LibEpiTitre).Titled(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LibEpiTitre).ToString());
columns.Add(c => c.TcDuree).Titled(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TcDuree).ToString()).Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}");//.Filterable(true);
columns.Add(c => c.LibSts).Titled(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LibSts).ToString()).Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(s => CustomRenderingOfStatut(s.Statut, s.LibPss));
columns.Add(c => c.DtModif).Titled(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DtModif).ToString()).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
columns.Add(c => c.LibPss).Titled(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LibPss).ToString());
columns.Add(c => c.DiffusionId).Titled(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DiffusionId).ToString());
```

I want to show a tooltip when hovering over the **DiffusionId** column. 
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
columns.Add(c => <span title='Tooltip Text'>c.DiffusionId</span>)
.Titled(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DiffusionId).ToString())
.Encoded(false);
```